# The user drop-down menu shows questions for which a user didn't gain any reputation change

Tags: discussion, support, activity-dropdown

I answered to my own question on this site, and accepted it to avoid the question gets automatically bumped. As result, my drop-down menu shows the question, even if the reputation didn't change.

Is there any case where such questions should be highlighted in the user drop-down menu?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a general sense, yes, rep-less question activity can be useful to know about. Votes, whether they have an impact or not, are meaningful. This lets you track the following.

- Votes and Acceptances on Community Wiki posts that you have
- Votes you receive on answers after you hit the reputation cap
- Accepted edit suggestions after you've already earned 1000 reputation from them, or hit the daily cap.

Normal reputation activity, you can see the reputation change and thus you'll know that something was voted. These activities, however, do not show such visual change, so the dropdown then becomes a pretty basic resource to get updates for these scenarios.

The only scenarios I can see it not being so useful is when you are accepting an answer to your own Community Wiki question or when you are self-accepting an answer, in both cases of which it's something of a given that you already know about the event. However, this is tied with how accepting an answer to any other question does give you +2, so for making the code simpler it's probably better to just let this exception slide.